# Update oracle table by joining 3 tables

Tags: oracle, left-join

using the below query to update table A by joining with two other tables E and S.
The below query is throwing an error in the 'From' part.
Found 'FROM': Expecting:end-of-input -or- LOG -or- RETURN RETURINNG -or- WHERE -or- ,

```sql
UPDATE A
   SET SEGMENT_TYPE_CUR = CASE
                            WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                             E.SEGMENT_TYPE
                            ELSE
                             NULL
                          END,
       CID_CUR = CASE
                   WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    E.CUST_ID
                   ELSE
                    NULL
                 END,
       RID_CUR = CASE
                   WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                    E.RID
                   ELSE
                    NULL
                 END,
       SEGMENT_1_CUR = CASE
                         WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                          E.SEGMENT_1
                         ELSE
                          S.SEGMENT_1
                       END,
       SEGMENT_2_CUR = CASE
                         WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                          E.SEGMENT_2
                         ELSE
                          S.SEGMENT_2
                       END,
       SEGMENT_3_CUR = CASE
                         WHEN E.ID IS NOT NULL AND E.SEGMENT_1 IS NOT NULL THEN
                          E.SEGMENT_3
                         ELSE
                          S.SEGMENT_3
                       END FROM TEST a LEFT JOIN RESTATE E on a.ID = E.ID LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                                                                                       FROM REFERENCE_SEGMENT
                                                                                      WHERE CURRENT_IND = 'Y'
                                                                                        AND SEG_IND = 'Y') S ON a.SUB_SEGMENT_CD = S.SEGMENT_REF_KEY
 WHERE a.SEGMENT_1 = 'BIZ'
   and TO_CHAR(a.update_date, 'yyyymm') = '202101'
```

Comment: After formatting the SQL statement, it should be pretty clear that the issue comes from the part which follows the `CASE ..WHEN..THEN..END` used for updating the column `SEGMENT_3_CUR`

Comment: Oracle doesn't support this syntax for the multi-table updates. You need a MERGE statement. Please post the sample data and expected output to get better help.

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a temp table by joining the source tables. Then using the temp table in my merge statement I am updating the target table.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).